# More duplicates

Tags: discussion, exact-duplicates

I'm wondering if anything should be done about the following 3 questions which seem to me like duplicates (like merge them):

- [is there a converse for the following Theorem? Equivalent systems of linear equations have exactly the same solutions](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/111757/28787)
- [proving that two systems of linear equations are equivalent if they have the same solutions](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/46050/28787)
- [2 linear systems: same solution set implies row equivalence; how to prove?](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/143718/28787)

Comment: Once you have enough reputation (250 points), you can "vote to close" as duplicates. This closes one question and leaves a pointer to the "duplicate" in the question. E.g., what happened [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/145150/742)

Comment: Just leave a comment; that way, users with voting privileges can decide if your proposals are sound...

Comment: @Arturo: correction. **250 rep points** is enough for a user to vote to close/re-open/delete his or her *own questions*. To vote on other questions requires **3000 rep points**.

Comment: @Willie:  Thanks for clearing that up.  I was a bit puzzled by what Arturo said, because I have never seen that I had the option to vote to close (and indeed it turns out I don't).